# Estimate the intergral of $f(x)g'(x)$ from $0$ to $3$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having a lot of trouble with this one, really can not get the correct solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because of $(fg)'=fg'+gf'$ the integral is
$$
f(3)g(3)-f(0)g(0)-\int_0^3 f'(x) g(x) dx = 36 - 2 \int_0^3 xg(x) dx
\approx
36 - 2\left[ 0.5 \cdot 0  + 0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 2.2 + \dots 0.5 \cdot 2.5 \cdot 3.3 \right]
$$
or you use the right endpoints
$$
\approx
36 - 2\left[ 0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 2.2 + \dots 0.5 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \right]
$$

Comment: it says that 36 is incorrect

Comment: have you subtracted the approximation (riemann sum)?

Comment: I am confused, what value did you get for the Riemann sum

Comment: @Benjiii: You need to approximate $ \int_0^3 xg(x) dx $ using Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1):

To estimate $\int_0^3 xg(x)\,dx$ you may apply Simpson's rule  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule 
$$\frac{b-a}{6}\Bigl(f(a)+4f\bigl((a+b)/2\bigr)+f(b)\Bigr)$$
on the intervals $[0,1]$, $[1,2]$, and $[2,3]$ to get
$$\int_0^3 xg(x)\,dx\approx\frac 16\bigl((0+4.4+2.5)+(2.5+18+6.2)+(6.2+31+12)\bigr)=12.3,$$
so the result should be $36-12.3=23.7$.