# Basic calculus integral estimation problem

Tags: calculus

> You are given the table below. $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline x & \color{red}2 & \color{red}4 & \color{red}6 & \color{red}8 & \color{red}{10}\\\hline f(x)&\color{red}{12}&\color{red}{23}&\color{red}{15}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{33}\\\hline\end{array}$$
>   Use the table and $n=4$ to estimate the following. Because the data is not monotone (only increasing or only decreasing), $$\int_{\color{red}{2}}^{\color{red}{10}}f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Is the under estimation : $12+15+6+6$ ? Or $2(12+15+6)$ ? Or $(12+15+6)$?

It's not a multiple choice, it's my assumptions. The first and third were wrong answers. So is is the second ?

Comment: What estimation technique are you supposed to be using?

Comment: @Silynn I did not know that there are multiple techniques to solve estimation.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of techniques to estimate an integral, the simplest is rectangular, which can be written as $\int_a^b f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(x_n)\Delta x_n$

Comment: ... but presumably you just learned a particular technique in the unit where this question was asked?

Comment: Do you know left and right Riemann sums? See a [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647226/estimate-the-intergral-of-fxgx-from-0-to-3).

Comment: The identical question is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860729/calculus-about-basic-integrals

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using the rectangular approximation, in which case you would do $2 (12+23+15+6) $, for a left Riemann sum, and for a right Riemann sum, $2 (23+15+6+33) $ by using the formula Silynn gave in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860826/basic-calculus-integral-estimation-problem#comment1775642_860826) (I'm on my phone, so LaTeX is hard. Sorry.).

Comment: You need to remove one of the points ($12$ or $33$ depending on left or right sum), right now it's a left sum on $2$ to $12$.

Comment: @Silynn Yeah, you're correct. Edited.

Comment: It was a wrong answer. I think because you gave me the left and right hand. However, the question is asking for over and under estimation. what shall i Do ?